# Early-stencil culling without early-z culling

Tags: opengl, stencil-buffer, culling

I already have an idea of the answer but I need to be sure.

I render a scene in two pass.
In the first pass, if depth test succeeds, I mark stencil bit as 1 :

```cpp
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilMask(GL_TRUE);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, GL_TRUE);
```

The second pass only writes where stencil is 1 :

```cpp
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, GL_TRUE); // Pass test if stencil value is 1
glStencilMask(GL_FALSE); // Don't write anything to stencil buffer
```

In fact, this works properly but I expected a huge increase in terms of performance.
The shader used in the second pass is particular : it uses `discard` and `gl_FragDepth` affectation.
That makes early-z culling impossible. Fortunately, I'm only interested in early-stencil culling.

So there is my question : is there a way to take advantage from early-stencil culling **without early-z culling** ?

---

This thread is very related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740841/early-stencil-culling), but I really need to use `discard` and `gl_FragDepth` affectation in the second shader...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as early stencil tests. Or early Z/depth tests for that matter. There are only [early *fragment* tests](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test), which happen to include the stencil and depth tests, but also other operations. They cannot be performed early in piecemeal; it's all early or all late.